# How to implement jquery live() instead of each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, tooltip

Hi I have been trying to get this script http://jsbin.com/ipajo5/ working but using .live() instead of .each() since the html table is populated on the fly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.bi').each(function () {
    // options
    var distance = 10;
    var time = 250;
    var hideDelay = 500;

    var hideDelayTimer = null;

    var beingShown = false;
    var shown = false;

    var trigger = $('.tt', this);
    var popup = $('.popup', this).css('opacity', 0);

    // set the mouseover and mouseout on both element
    $([trigger.get(0), popup.get(0)]).mouseover(function () {
      if (hideDelayTimer) clearTimeout(hideDelayTimer);

      if (beingShown || shown) {
        return;
      } else {
        beingShown = true;    
        popup.css({
          top: $(this).position().top-150,
          left: $(this).position().left-100,
          display: 'block' 
        })
        .animate({
          top: '-=' + distance + 'px',
          opacity: 1
        }, time, 'swing', function() {
          beingShown = false;
          shown = true;
        });
      }
    }).mouseout(function () {
      if (hideDelayTimer) clearTimeout(hideDelayTimer);

      hideDelayTimer = setTimeout(function () {
        hideDelayTimer = null;
        popup.animate({
          top: '-=' + distance + 'px',
          opacity: 0
        }, time, 'swing', function () {
          shown = false;
          popup.css('display', 'none');
        });
      }, hideDelay);
    });
  });

});​
```

Note. In some threads it is recomended to use delegate() instead live() for performance, but after many days I only want this popup/tooltip to work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually don't need to change anything. I have a similar function, but a little more extended. Just remove it from the document.ready function.
Mind you, you are better of using delegate() instead of live(). Due to bubbling. If you want a fully automated page, that is uploaded on the fly take a look at [jaltiere.com](http://www.jaltiere.com/index.php/2010/04/08/jquery-delegates/)

But you will need to fully rewrite your script. Besides, both live() and delegate() are difficult to set up with mouseover and mouseout events.

No caching in the document.ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });});
```

On page load, do your ajax-call and call your script as a seperate function:

```
$(function() {
$.get("ajaxpage.php", function(data) {
    $("#recent").html(data);
    bifunct();
});});
```

Seperate function for an update:

```
function ajaxcall(){
$.get("ajaxpage.php?", function(data) {
    $("#recent").html(data);
    bifunct();
});};
```

And now your script. I've changed your mouseover and mouseout to mouseenter and mouseleave. They work slightly better.

```
bifunct = function(){
$('.bi').each(function () {
    // options
    var distance = 10;
    var time = 250;
    var hideDelay = 500;
    var hideDelayTimer = null;
    var beingShown = false;
    var shown = false;
    var trigger = $('.tt', this);
    var popup = $('.popup', this).css('opacity', 0);

    // set the mouseover and mouseout on both element
    $([trigger.get(0), popup.get(0)]).mouseenter(function () {
        if (hideDelayTimer) clearTimeout(hideDelayTimer);
        if (beingShown || shown) {
            return;
        } else {
            beingShown = true;    
            popup.css({
                top: $(this).position().top-150,
                left: $(this).position().left-100,
                display: 'block' 
            })
            .animate({
                top: '-=' + distance + 'px',
                opacity: 1
            }, time, 'swing', function() {
                beingShown = false;
                shown = true;
            });
        }
    }).mouseleave(function () {
        if (hideDelayTimer) clearTimeout(hideDelayTimer);
        hideDelayTimer = setTimeout(function () {
            hideDelayTimer = null;
            popup.animate({
                top: '-=' + distance + 'px',
                opacity: 0
            }, time, 'swing', function () {
                shown = false;
                popup.css('display', 'none');
            });
        }, hideDelay);
    });
});}
```

If you want to update, simply put this in your body, or change it to call the ajaxcall-function:

```
<a onclick="ajaxcall();return false" href="#"> update </a>
```

Comment: I have turned it into a function and added it at the end of the drawing functions (I have 2 tables on the page that work differently). I will try with mouseenter and mouseleave later after more testing on different browsers and complete all functionalities of the page. Thank you @Daniel

Answer (score 5):

Replacing ".each()" with ".live()" makes very little sense.  The ".each()" facility is provided to iterate over parts of the DOM that have been matched by a selector, or otherwise to iterate functionally through the constituents of a jQuery object.

All that ".live()" can do is help with event handling. If you need to do other things to parts of your page as they're loaded dynamically, you'll have to piece that together yourself in the "success" handlers for dynamic updates, or some other similar thing.

Comment: I know .each() is to iterate over a jQuery object, executing a function for each matched element and live() is to attach a handler to the event for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future. So maybe my question is not very descriptive, I want to get the script working but I am failing to attach the functionality of the script to recreated on the fly html elements, which are not matched by each() and maybe get them with live()

Comment: @Joaquín Duaso OK that is good - so what is it that you want to do?

Comment: @Joaquin, so you want people to interpret a pretty complex script with absolutely no background information and to read your mind as to what you would like it to do?

Comment: The table of the example is created and recreated as you interact with the application, when you hover the table cell with a domain extension in a link a popup/tooltip hoverable hidden div, wich is inside the table cell with some options appears.

Comment: @Yads yep the script is complex. Perhaps I should have posted it as pseudocode as there is a working example link with the code.